log files are vanishing from the working directory when trying to read and export them in Python 3.11
I am defining a logger and periodically exporting the content to a blob. I've been using it for some time with DBR 10.4/python 3.8 without any issue. However we've moved to DBR 15.2/python 3.11, and now the logger function is working as expected. But whenever I'm trying to read and export it it's throwing the following error:

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory

The weird part is while exporting the first time it works without any error. But the next time the log files are not visible to python. following is the screenshot of the situation:

which is coming from the following lines:

Following is the code where I'm defining my logger:
import logging
from logging.handlers import RotatingFileHandler
from logging import FileHandler

def define_logger(file_name, debug=False, clear_handlers=False, stream_level_debug=False, info=True):
    """
    :param file_name: Name of the .log file
    :param debug: If true, creates debug level .log file
    :param clear_handlers: to clear the previous log file handlers.
    :param stream_level_debug: receive the log debug level on console.
    :param info: If true, creates info level log file.

        Defines the logger and arranges the handlers based on the parameters.
    :return: logger instance

    Enables log functionality.
    """
    #file_name = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), file_name)
    print(file_name)
    # define a logger
    logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
    # the level should be the lowest level set in handlers
    logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
    # This is for removing all the handler from the logger instance
    # First time you are running this you don't need it, when you want to define new logger specify
    if clear_handlers is True:
        logger.handlers.clear()
        while len(logger.handlers) > 0:
            logger.removeHandler(logger.handlers[0])

    # Format can be arranged
    # datefmt for formatting the time.
    log_format = logging.Formatter('[%(levelname)s] - %(asctime)s - %(filename)s - %(funcName)s - %(message)s',
     datefmt='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M')

    # For logging into console
    stream_handler = logging.StreamHandler()
    stream_handler.setFormatter(log_format)
    if not stream_level_debug:
        stream_handler.setLevel(logging.INFO)
    else:
        stream_handler.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
    logger.addHandler(stream_handler)

    # For logging into Info.log
    if info:
        info_handler = RotatingFileHandler('{}_info.log'.format(file_name), backupCount=1)
        info_handler.setFormatter(log_format)
        info_handler.setLevel(logging.INFO)
        logger.addHandler(info_handler)

    # If cfg['log_debug'] = True then it will also capture debug level logs and puts it into _debug.log file
    if debug:
        debug_handler = RotatingFileHandler('{}_debug.log'.format(file_name), backupCount=1)
        debug_handler.setFormatter(log_format)
        debug_handler.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
        logger.addHandler(debug_handler)

    return logger


# main
mainlog = str(datetime.now().strftime("Dataprep_%Y-%B-%d-at%H-%M"))
log = define_logger(mainlog, debug=cfg['log_debug'], clear_handlers=True, stream_level_debug=cfg["stream_level_debug"])
log.info('=' * 80)
blob_outpath = cfg['blob_outpath']
log.debug('blob_outpath {}'.format(blob_outpath))
# Upload the log to blob drive
log2blob(env, mainlog, blob_outpath, cfg['log_debug']) # This works

Any solution/pointer to tackle this issue will be really helpful.
EDIT:
I additionally tried to specify a log folder and use the full path + filename to create the log and read it. Although the logs are created but iIt's still throwing the same error. After getting the error if I run os.listdir(logpath) I don't see the missing logfile in the list. But if I run %sh ls -als logpath I can see the 'missing' log file listed. If I run os.listdir(logpath) again, the missing logfiles appear. Not sure if the following lines are creating the issue somehow:
with open(full_path, "r+b") as data:
        blob.upload_blob(data)


maybe a silly question : did you actually print the full log file paths in both versions ? (see Path.absolute())

Yes, in one of my tests, I did that, and both of them are being read from the working directory. Not sure how/whether to track these log files if they are getting moved somehow.

to me, an actual MCVE with all the relevant software versions is required. You could use a code peer, sometimes the cause is obvious and in plain sight, but somehow a "tunnel effect" occurs.


Can you post the cluster config, single/multi-node? 2. Post the code that calls define_logger(). 3. Run id command from shell and python code (print(os.popen("id").read())) and post the output? 4. From shell post the permissions on directory where logs are. ls -al <logdir> or ls -al `dirname <logfile>` 


you could create the writing directory ot the log-file.name dynamically, so the old files are   retained perhaps. Better would be of course, finding a parameter to influence the behavior.

This screams permissions issue. Are you running any of this as root by chance?

@x3l51, all the codes are running from user workspace and not from root. Plus I don't have this issue while using the same code in python 3.8

@Kashyap, 1. it's a multi-node cluster with 2-8 workers autoscaled. DBR version 15.2
2. following is the code where I'm calling it:
`mainlog = str(datetime.now().strftime("Dataprep_%Y-%B-%d-at%H-%M"))
log = define_logger(mainlog, debug=cfg['log_debug'],
clear_handlers=True, stream_level_debug=cfg["stream_level_debug"])
log.info('=' * 80)
blob_outpath = cfg['blob_outpath']
log.debug('blob_outpath {}'.format(blob_outpath))

# Upload the log to blob drive
log2blob(env, mainlog, blob_outpath, cfg['log_debug']) # This works`


@Kashyap
3.
When I try the id command for my log folder:
/bin/sh: 1: /logpath: Permission denied
4. the permission for log folder:
1 -rwxrwxrwx 1 root root  428 Jul 30 10:00 Dataprep_2024-July-30-at10-00_info.log
Odd that the permission is denied.

Just to add on the os.popen().read(), I used the same command in my python 3.8 environment and it returned a blank output. Although (print(os.popen("id").read())) returns uid=0(root) gid=0(root) groups=0(root) same as the 3.11 env where I'm facing the issue.
